# Spring MVC. How Pageable actually works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination

Please help me to figure out how Spring parses HTTP GET parameters from the request into the Pageable-suited object without any additional annotations like @RequestBody, @RequestParam, etc.

So, I send a request that looks like this: 
**GET /questions?page=0&size=2&sort=createdAt,desc**.
As an argument of the getQuestions method I get an object consisted of three fields like page, size, sort. But, how this magic actually works?

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @GetMapping("/questions")
    public Page<Question> getQuestions(Pageable pageable) {
        return questionRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }


    @PostMapping("/questions")
    public Question createQuestion(@Valid @RequestBody Question question) {
        return questionRepository.save(question);
    }

    // other restful methods
}
```

Comment: It's not magic. Spring knows you want a `Pagable` - it's right there in the method argument. Then it simply looks for well known query parameters. Trivially simple really. You can register your own [data binders](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) and do the same for your own types in fact.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web,